# ".class" error in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to run this program but I cannot, the  compiler is sending me a ".class" error. 
Can somebody help me with my problem and if it is possible a general tip about ".class" error?
Here is the program:

```
    import java.io.*;
    class Bus
    {
        private int kostos;
        private int plithos;
        private int typepiv;
        Bus(int x,int y,int z)
        {
            kostos=x;
            plithos=y;
            typepiv=z;

        }
        public void KB(int[] x)
        {
        try{
           for(int i=1;i<5;i++)
             {

                 if(typepiv==2)
                 {
                     plithos=plithos+plithos/2;
                     kostos=kostos-kostos/2;
                 }
                 if(typepiv==3)
                 {
                     plithos=plithos-plithos/5;
                     kostos=kostos-kostos*25/100;
                 }
                 if(typepiv==1)
                 {
                     plithos=plithos;
                     kostos=kostos;
                 }
                     x[i]=plithos*kostos; 
             } 
         } catch(Exception ex){
              ex.printStackTrace();
         }
      }
   }

  class testBus
  {
     public static void main(String args[])
     {
          String leof[]=new String[4];
          int leof1[][]=new int[4][3];
          for(int i=1;i<5;i++)
             {
                 System.out.println("dwste onoma leoforiou");
                 leof[i]=UserInput.getString();
                 System.out.println("dwste kostos thesis enilika");
                 leof1[i][1]=UserInput.getInteger();
                 System.out.println("dwste plithos thesewn");
                 leof1[i][2]=UserInput.getInteger();
                 System.out.println("dwste tupos epibath gia enilikes=1,gia
                 paidia=2,gia    suntaksiouxous=3");
                 leof1[i][3]=UserInput.getInteger();
                 Bus leof2=new Bus(leof1[i][1],leof1[i][2],leof1[i][3]);
              }
           int KostEnoik[]=new int[4];
     ----->leof2.KB(KostEnoik);
           System.out.print("onoleo");
           System.out.print("  ");
           System.out.print("plithos");
           System.out.print("  ");
           System.out.print("kost(EURO)");
           System.out.print("typepiv");
           System.out.print("  ");
           System.out.print("apotelesma kostEnoik");
           for(int g=1;g<5;g++)
              {
                  System.out.print(leof[g]);
                  System.out.print(leof1[g][2]);
                  System.out.print(leof1[g][1]);
                  System.out.print(leof1[g][3]);
                  System.out.print(KostEnoik[g]);
              }
          }
      }
```

the compiler message says :
testBus.java:56:error:cannot find symbol
    leof2.KB(KostEnoik);
    symbol:bariable leof2
    location:class testBus
1 error

Comment: Even if the compiler error doesn't mean anything to you, it probably means something to other people here. Can you copy the exact text of the compiler error?

Comment: i put leof2.KB(KostEnoik); inside the loop and now the compiler complile the file thnxs very much everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the array brackets `[]` when invoking `KB`

```
leof2.KB(KostEnoik);
```

and remove the preceding enclosing brace `}`.

Aside: Java naming conventions indicate that variables start with a *lowercase* letter e.g. `kostEnoik`. Also consider giving the method `KB` a meaningful name, e.g. `calculateCost`

Read [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367)

Comment: i tried like this too but not it says that it cannot find symbol

Comment: Did you import `UserInput`?

Answer (score 1):

concern is with your access

leof2.KB(KostEnoik[]);

You are trying to access the "leof2" variable outside of the scope in which it is defined i.e. outside for loop and scope is upto for loop and that's why the compiler will not be able to find that varialble .

Comment: @user3194888 have u get my friend

Answer (score 0):

```
    leof1[i][3]=UserInput.getInteger();
    Bus leof2=new Bus(leof1[i][1],leof1[i][2],leof1[i][3]);
}
int KostEnoik[]=new int[4];
leof2.KB(KostEnoik[]);
```

1. You are trying to access the "leof2" variable outside of the scope in which it's defined (in this particular case, the for loop) and that's not allowed.
2. method KB takes an int array as argument, but you don't have to add the `[]` when passing the argument.  The correct line is

   leof2.KB(KostEnoik);

However, there's something pretty odd with you logic: you're repeatedly (for loop) setting leof2, but only the last iteration of the loop will have any effect.  I'm almost certain that that's not what you actually want, but the correct answer to where `Bus leof2` should actually be defined depends on the correction of that issue.

Comment: hwat i want is that the array leof[1][1] and leof1[2][1] to go to the method i really dont know how to do this keep in mind that i am first year student so i dont know very much

Comment: ok I see.  I think you're better off starting over, because the logic of your program is quite twisted due to all the different arrays you're using, and once you solve the issues mentioned in this question you'll be facing a number of array index of of bounds  conditions (hint: the last element of int a[4] is a[3]).  Ideally try to group all data that describe 1 line in a separate class and move the KB method to that class.  That will be a lot clearer, and a lot more object oriented.

Answer (score 0):

`leof2.KB(KostEnoik);` this is the main culprit. whether you have imported `UserInput`.
Also try to go through the [Java Basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/)

any method can be invoked using `object` when it is `non static` or  class name when it is `static`. Please consider this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. Get leof2 object out side the For Loop.
2. Don't type [] when you pass the array as argument "leof2.KB(KostEnoik[]);".